# Why doesn't the normal reaction on one object doesn't cancel with normal reaction exerted by other object

Tags: forces

I was going through the question just as same below. He said to find normal reaction between 2 objects. So, why they aren't cancelling each other i.e Normal reaction of M1 on M2 and normal reaction of M2 on M1? [image]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by cancelling each other, but they indeed are equal and opposite, but without showing your work, we cannot say where you are wrong.

Comment: Hint: Assume that the two objects will stick together, so that their common acceleration will be the same as if they were a single object with mass $m_1+m_2$ Given a mass and a force, you can find the acceleration, right? Now you also are given the mass of the right hand object alone, and you just found the acceleration of it. So, given the mass and the acceleration of the right hand object, how can you find the force that is causing that acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the two masses as a single system then the two normal forces between the two objects do indeed cancel each other out and can be ignored.

If you want to calculate the size of the one of the forces (which will be the same size as the other) then you can not treat the two masses as a single system.  I would suggest by focusing on $M_2$.  The normal force from $M_1$ is what is pushing it to the right.  In this case the two normal forces do not cancel each other out **because they are not acting on the same object**.

Answer (score -1):

From your diagram, they should not cancel each other since you are exerting a force F on the small block that touches the large block. I don't see any corresponding force going from right to left such that your force F and the corresponding force reach equilibrium. I think this equilibrium condition is what you mean by 'canceling.'